# how to parse JSON Response(Data) in javascript.

Tags: javascript, json

i am little new to javascript..Can anyone help me out from here.My JSON Response is like below:And i want to parse it and show it in the Table.

And my javascript code is below:

```
function parseData() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/NJqfdNMx-";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function myFunction(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        var i;
        var out = "<table>";
     for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
             out += "<tr><td>" +
             arr[i].text +
            "</td><td>" +
             arr[i].text +
            "</td><td>" +
            arr[i].text +
            "</td></tr>";
      }
      out += "</table>";
      document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }
```

}

Comment: `var response = $.parseJSON(data);` it is.

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Variable arr is coming undefined object.Better you can through url..so that you will get more close@Leopard

Comment: `My JSON Response is like below` - there is no JSON below ... only your script. Did you forget to add it to the question?

Comment: Please  go through my url http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/NJqfdNMx-@JaromandaX

Comment: I think you'll find that `var arr` is **not** an array ... it's an object, with a single property called `text` - text is an object with 5 properties, 4 of which are arrays ... so you have to go at least 2 levels deep to get to an array

Comment: @VikashKumar - I shouldn't **have** to go anywhere external if you knew how to ask a with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes Jaromanda ..you are right..but how to reach there to get that value@JaromandaX

Answer (score 1):

Your `JSON` response contains `object` it doesn't directly contain `array` so you can't loop on response directly.

Your `JSON` response contains `object` with property `text` which contains further properties.

```
var arr = JSON.parse(response);
var text = arr.text;
```

This is value of `text`

```
{itemCount: 31, sleepActivities: Array[26], runActivities: Array[1], freePlayActivities: Array[3], bikeActivities: Array[1]}
```

Now you can loop on `sleepActivities` or `runActivities` or `freePlayActivities` or `bikeActivities`. You can loop over any array you want to get data.

```
for(i = 0; i < text.sleepActivities.length; i++) {
//your code  
}
```

Comment: let me try it @Leopard..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Need your Json data or Please go through this site
[W3School JSON Handling Methods](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp)

which helps you more

Comment: `JSON Response which i have is different` - wow, w3fools didn't have example code that exactly duplicates your particular issue?! How odd

Answer (score 0):

Your response contains object but you don't need use JSON.parse. Because the    response is pure JSON. You need to follow the below steps

```
var arr = response.text
```

it will return below result

```
Object {itemCount: 31, sleepActivities: Array[26], runActivities: Array[1],    freePlayActivities: Array[3], bikeActivities: Array[1]}
```

for eg if you want to take sleepActivities from the response. Follow the process

```
var sleepActivities = response.text.sleepActivities
$.each(sleepActivities ,function(i,val){
    console.log(val.heartRateSummary.averageHeartRate);
})
```

Comment: @vikash, Above eg is shown to take averageHeartRate